# Mongo replicaSet dispersed over all continents

Tags: mongodb-3.2, master-slave-replication

I have problem in operating mongo replicaSet which works on all continents. 
The primary data is located in Europe and want to replicate it distant locations in US, Brasil, Tokyo, Sydney and Dublin.

Unfortunately I'm keep getting errors like this

```
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.990+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to mongo-pcluster-7:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.991+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to mongo-pcluster-3:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.991+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to mongo-pcluster-6:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.992+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to mongo-pcluster-2:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.992+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo-pcluster-7:27017 - ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.993+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo-pcluster-3:27017 - ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.993+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo-pcluster-6:27017 - ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
05/12/2017 18:23:192017-12-05T17:23:19.993+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to mongo-pcluster-2:27017 - ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
05/12/2017 18:23:242017-12-05T17:23:24.990+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo-pcluster-7:27017
05/12/2017 18:23:242017-12-05T17:23:24.992+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo-pcluster-3:27017
05/12/2017 18:23:242017-12-05T17:23:24.992+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo-pcluster-6:27017
05/12/2017 18:23:242017-12-05T17:23:24.992+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to mongo-pcluster-2:27017
```

and the status of the cluster keep failing into recovering.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
    {
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:54.400Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(7),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "members" : [
            {
                "_id" : 0,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-4:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 1,
                "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                "uptime" : 1107523,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512493794, 15),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:09:54Z"),
                "electionTime" : Timestamp(1512298906, 1),
                "electionDate" : ISODate("2017-12-03T11:01:46Z"),
                "configVersion" : 10,
                "self" : true
            },
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-5:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 2,
                "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                "uptime" : 1106965,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512493794, 15),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:09:54Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:54.093Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:52.845Z"),
                "pingMs" : NumberLong(3),
                "syncingTo" : "mongo-pcluster-4:27017",
                "configVersion" : 10
            },
            {
                "_id" : 2,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-1:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 3,
                "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                "uptime" : 195019,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512492648, 63),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T16:50:48Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:54.371Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:52.608Z"),
                "pingMs" : NumberLong(326),
                "syncingTo" : "mongo-pcluster-5:27017",
                "configVersion" : 10
            },
            {
                "_id" : 3,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-2:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 2,
                "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                "uptime" : 195016,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512493498, 10),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:04:58Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:52.537Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:53.447Z"),
                "pingMs" : NumberLong(27),
                "syncingTo" : "mongo-pcluster-5:27017",
                "configVersion" : 10
            },
            {
                "_id" : 4,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-3:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 3,
                "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                "uptime" : 195024,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512492759, 138),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T16:52:39Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:53.259Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:52.384Z"),
                "pingMs" : NumberLong(131),
                "configVersion" : 10
            },
            {
                "_id" : 5,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-6:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 3,
                "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                "uptime" : 195000,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512492675, 19),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T16:51:15Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:53.476Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:49.488Z"),
                "pingMs" : NumberLong(241),
                "configVersion" : 10
            },
            {
                "_id" : 6,
                "name" : "mongo-pcluster-7:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 3,
                "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                "uptime" : 195015,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1512492651, 65),
                    "t" : NumberLong(7)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T16:50:51Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:54.027Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-12-05T17:11:52.632Z"),
                "pingMs" : NumberLong(306),
                "configVersion" : 10
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
    }
    rs0:PRIMARY>
```

How to make the settings for this replicaSet to work steady on long distance links.

My current config is as below. I increased timeout to 60seconds which seems to be way then needed on this distances but the increase has changed nothing.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> cfg = rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rspreredner0",
    "version" : 10,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-4:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 500,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-5:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 200,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-1:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-2:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-3:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-6:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "host" : "mongo-pcluster-7:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 60,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5a15edbfe2c98aee31ae2c4f")
    }
}
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it didn't change anything is that your config have `"protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1)` and this `heartbeatTimeoutSecs` applies only when protocolVersion is zero (0).

You should use `settings.electionTimeoutMillis` wich description you can find [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/replica-configuration/).